# mocha test on uploaded csv

Tags: javascript, csv, mocha.js, chai

So im using this code to upload and display the rows in a csv file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
          var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
          if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
              if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      var table = $("<table />");
                      var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                          var row = $("<tr />");
                          var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                          for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                              var cell = $("<td />");
                              cell.html(cells[j]);
                              row.append(cell);
                          }
                          table.append(row);
                      }
                      $("#dvCSV").html('');
                      $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                  }
                  reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
              } else {
                  alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
              }
          } else {
              alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
          }
      });
  });
  </script>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
  <hr />
  <div id="dvCSV">
  </div>
```

How could i test each row cell to check if it is a string or integer
I need to use the mochaJS framework. Or if there is any other framework which could validate each cell ?

The csv data is exported like so:

```
name     age      score
```

So i would need to go to the first row and test the name, then test the age and then score.

Comment: I doubt if MochaJS is the right tool to validate csv files.

Comment: agreed...qunit is a better choice for testing your dom. use mocha if you want to unit test your logic that parses the dom.

Comment: any example you can point me to @Daniel_L

Comment: https://qunitjs.com